# Best Graphics card (Setup) for three, high-res monitors attached to desktop

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hardware, amd-graphics

I want to build powerful desktop with triple monitor setup. I have one Dell UltraSharp U2713HM (27 inches, 2560x1440) and I was thinking about getting two more. Would it be possible to have those three working with Ubuntu (Kubuntu) on any graphics card out there today? What is the best option if it comes to choosing particular model? Should I use proprietary drivers or some open sourced ones?

I am not a gamer. I mostly develop on my machines and running some computational tasks, but I would rather like to spend some more money and have setup where I don't see any lagging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best triple head display setup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226579/best-triple-head-display-setup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For triple-monitor support you need to be aware that most non-DisplayPort graphics cards only support two simultaneous outputs, because they only have two PLLs, and hence can generate two pixel clocks. Since you are planning to use 3 DisplayPort monitors (Dell U2713HM) this should not be a problem, but if you change your mind and use non-DP monitors, it is an important constraint. If you have absolutely identical monitors (same internals, same frequency pixel clock) then some drivers will allow you to share a single pixel clock between two displays (the Intel driver will for sure, and I think AMD's open source driver will). For more details see [Wikipedia Intel graphics and three active displays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_and_Iris_Graphics#Three_active_displays).

Your options are:

- Intel HD integrated graphics. Intel GPU comes with your CPU, and is well supported with open source drivers. The Intel drivers can share PLLs for triple-head on non-DP monitors. You will need a motherboard with three video outputs, or laptop with DisplayPort/Thunderbolt ports.
- (for DVI/HDMI monitors) AMD Radeon with a Sapphire FleX card. Sapphire's FleX is a brand name for cards that have a third PLL, and so can support three simultaneous outputs.
- (for DP monitors) AMD Radeon Eyefinity supports upto 6 monitors with the open source radeon driver. You can also use this card with non-DP monitors, but you will need active DP adaptors. For more details see [Using six monitors with AMD's open-source driver](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?80759-Using-Six-Monitors-With-AMD-s-Open-Source-Linux-Driver/page1).
- Nvidia Surround with the closed source driver. According to the answers to the question [Linux + “nVidia surround” + 3 monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/476012/linux-nvidia-surround-3-monitors) this should work correctly with upto 4 monitors.
- You do not necessarily need multiple video outputs if you have DisplayPort 1.2 monitors or a DisplayPort MST Hub. In this case, you can use a graphics card or laptop with a single DisplayPort output and connect it to multiple DP 1.2 monitors with "daisy-chaining", or connect it with a single cable to the DisplayPort MST Hub, and then connect the MST Hub to your monitors. [This option is working](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?px=MTY4MDI&page=news_item) but not quite ready yet - the patches are expected to appear in the Linux 3.16 kernel.

  It should be a lot more common to see this option in the future, as it enables a laptop with single mini-DP connector to drive multiple monitors. (For space and cost reasons, laptops do not usually feature multiple DP ports).

Answer (score 0):

This is not even a question. ATI drivers for linux seriously lag behind in terms of non-standard setups. People say it all the time. 
The real problem is if you should use one NVIDIA with three monitors or two on one and one on other. Of that, I can't help really. I did use 3 monitors on 1 NVIDIA, but they where 1080p only - I am not sure if DVI outputs og GTX7*** can hanle more.

Comment: People say that about the closed source AMD drivers. The open source drivers are a different matter.

Comment: [not so fast on multiple NVIDIA cards...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682164/can-ubuntu-split-the-desktop-across-two-graphics-cards)