# Cursor trapped on secondary X screen

Tags: 12.10, ati, xorg, dualhead

### Problem

My mouse keeps getting stuck on DISPLAY=:0.1.

### Setup

Three monitors on two cards with two X Screens.

- Radeon HD 6950 **(00)**

  - DISPLAY=:0.0
  - Monitor 1 over HDMI
  - Monitor 2 over DVI
- Radeon HD 6950 **(01)**

  - DISPLAY=:0.1
  - Monitor 3 (named 7 by aticonfig) over DVI
- [xorg.conf](https://ezcrypt.it/Yb6n#VAClXiLS3bk7ZGlgN90kDqBU)

[image]

### Explanation

Previously on 12.10/12.04, I have been able to get a similar setup working by invoking `aticonfig --init=dual-head` and then `aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0` (The latter makes sure my displays have no black boundaries/No Underscan).

While I am aware of bugs in Nautilus/Compiz that make a second X Screen buggy and messy, I have never had my cursor get trapped on it.

Comment: How stuck? Like STUCK? Or sticky edges stuck?

Comment: Not sticky edges.  I've been diagnosing/troubleshooting for weeks now.  The cursor becomes trapped inside of :0.1.  When the cursor is brought to the edge of the screen (to return to :0.0), it completely resets to the other side.  It's like playing Super Mario Brothers 3 on one of those levels where you can go through either horizontal side and return to the other side, except it's only one directional: it always appears back on the left side in the same exact vertical/horizontal position.  I have to reset X (logout/login) to reset my cursor to :0.0.

Answer (score 0):

The only similiar topic i found is  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106683/any-really-decent-way-to-get-three-monitors)

Did you already try to configure your screensetup direcly via terminal using xrandr?