# Ubuntu 21.04 with three external monitors

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, dell, screen

I want to use three screens with my Ubuntu 21.04 laptop.

My hardware:

- Laptop: Dell Precision 5510
- Dock: Dell Dock WD19 (2x DisplayPort, 1x HDMI)
- Screen 1: DELL P2719H -> Connected via DisplayPort
- Screen 2: Dell UP2716D -> Connected via DisplayPort -> capable of 2560 x 1440, but I only use 1920 x 1080 because the other is limited to 1920 x 1080 and the monitors only work at the same resolution (which is okay for me)

I updated to Ubuntu 21.04 today an promptly ran into the issue that my two external screens are recognized but remain dark. I can configure all three screens (the laptop screen being the third) but the laptop screen is the only one working. I can move windows to the other two screens but as said, they remain black. Both screens say there is "No DP signal from your device".

xrandr says:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1-2-8 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-1-2-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Maybe there is an issue with "*+" not being at the same resolution for the last display?

I've been thinking to buy a third screen and keep my laptop lid closed for some time now. I want to buy the DELL P2719H (= Screen 1) again and use three external screens. This problem made me consider this option even harder now.

Now my question is: Can I run three external monitors with my setup? And can I run the two DELL P2719H  (= Screen 1 and the new one) via DisplayPort and Dell UP2716D (= Screen 2) via HDMI at the same time? Or is it not possible to to combine HDMI and DisplayPort?

If not possible, would it work when I daisy-chain tow screens? Connect Screen 1 and Screen 2 to my Dock and chain the new Screen 3 to Screen 2?

Ideally I'd like to have Screen 1 and the new Screen 3 in landscape orientation and Screen 2 in portrait.

If nothing works, maybe someone has at least an idea how I can fix my two screens from going dark? That way I'd be stuck with two external screens and my laptop screen, but at least I can use three screens again. With my Ubuntu 20.04 setup (before updating to 21.04) two external screens and the laptop screen worked. So I don't think it is a hardware issue.

WIth 21.04 I selected "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary, tested)" in "Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers". I also tried "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-465 (proprietary)" with the same result.

Comment: Many laptops only support the native display +1.  It's a hardware limitation.

Comment: It is not a hareware limitation. WIth my Ubuntu 20.04 before the uprate, it worked.

Comment: Does anyone know if I can use two monitors with DP and one with HDMI at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

**Dell Dock WD19**

You may have to update the firmware on the dock. Get Dell's updater utility at https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=p20vd. Windows or FreeDOS probably required to run the updater.

**Dell Precision 5510**

You may also have to update your Dell Precision 5510 BIOS. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the Dell web site to check for a newer BIOS.

**Update #1:**

This is a known problem with 21.04. See https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67714 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1931547 and https://www.displaylink.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?s=b619aee8537f35e5f462128bae6064dc&f=29.

Comment: Just confirmed: I have the latest bios version installed. But again, this setup worked in the past. I have no clue, why Ubuntu 21.04 does not get along with my screens. While updating I went from 20.04 to 20.10 and straight away to 21.04 ... with 20.10 it worked as well.

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld Check the dock firmware.

Comment: I updated the dock firmware to latest. Still only my laptop screen works. the other two are detected by ubuntu but ramain dark. As said, it worked int he past. I'm using nvidia  drivers. While updating I tested with a windows machine. With windows the dock was able to use both screens perfectly fine. So I guess it is an issue with ubuntu.

Comment: Closing the lid of my laptop in hope that the external screens would work did not do it either. The laptop was not sleeping because I heard sounds of (un-)mounting USB HDDs. But the screens remain dark.

Comment: Does the dock have both front and rear USB/USB-C ports to connect to the system? Or does it just connect via a DP? Try using the other port on the dock.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Using another port is not possible. The USB-C cable is fixed to the dock (not pluggable at the dock) and is using the only USB-C port on my laptop. The dock has 2 DP-ports which I use for the monitors. But I don't think the ports are the issue as it worked with Ubuntu 20.04 perfectly. I did not change or unplug any cable. I just updated my laptop.

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld At the GRUB menu, boot to a prior kernel and see if things start working again. Report back.

Comment: How can I boot into prior kernels? these are all my options:

`UEFI: (1) ubuntu OTHER OPTIONS: (2) bios setup, (3) bios flash update, (4) diagnostics, (5) change boot mode settings`

Comment: I discovered a new message ... when I boot or shutdown I see `drm *error* link training unsuccessful`. Just discovered this message, was hidden behind ubuntu logos. I have no clou what this means. But maybe this has some effect ...

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld Looking at your comment, it looks like you're looking at the BIOS menu, not the GRUB menu. Af boot time, do you see a menu that shows what booting options that you have? Do you dual-boot with Windows? If you see the GRUB menu, choose the second choice, Additional Options, then select an older kernel to boot, and see if your problem is solved.

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld See https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67714 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1931547 and https://www.displaylink.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?s=b619aee8537f35e5f462128bae6064dc&f=29. I updated my answer.

Comment: The links you posted suggest that an up-to-date kernel could fix the issue. I'm running `Linux 5.11.0-22-generic` kernel.  At https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ there is a 5.11.22 listed. Is this a newer version than my kernel? Is so I'd try to update to this kernel version.

Comment: For completeness: I'm not running windows or any other OS next to my Ubuntu. Only Ubuntu. I don't see a grub menu ... or at least I don't recognize a grub menu, problem here might be the person in front of the computer

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld With a single-boot configuration, the GRUB menu would be hidden. To see it, hold down the ESC (or SHIFT for older BIOS computers) key during boot, then you'll see the GRUB menu, and you can select an older kernel. Are you running Wayland or Xorg? Check at the Password login window. You'll also need to check that you have the latest DisplayLink driver and Xorg server installed.

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld Did you check the items from my last comment? Any difference if you switch to Wayland?

Comment: I'm running xorg: echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPEreturn x11. This is how I setup my machine trying to get my screens running: https://gitlab.com/sommerfeld.sebastian/kobol/-/blob/main/src/main/setup/00-setup-drivers.sh

Comment: I've got enough ... I decided to revert back to Ubuntu 20.10 with kernel version 5.8.0-59-generic and now everything works like a charm again. ... Thank you for you help and your timely answers. At the very least I learned a lot through our discussion. I will give it a shot some other time in hopes that the known bug with the xorg-server is fixed by then.

Answer (score 0):

With a Lenovo X1, Dell Dock WD19 and 2 DELL U2415 monitors I had the same problem. Updating to latest kernel 5.11.0-25 had no effect at first, but playing with the resolution! My internal screen has native resolution of 2560x1440, the Dells support 1920x1200. After setting the internal resolution to 1920x1200 suddenly both external monitors worked. I could even restore the internal resolution to the original setting of 2560x1440 and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Ubuntu installed, but I know from hear-saying that even with a fix from [Unsupported kernel version: 6.0](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/issues/757#issuecomment-1352367089), the three screens did not work. It turns out to be much easier, no trick from a repository needed.

Just try the official driver from the [DisplayLink driver website](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683482-displaylink-support-for-ubuntu-now-available) --> "DisplayLink support for Ubuntu now available".

Releases are available for Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS onwards.

I know that this works on Ubuntu 22.04, at the time of writing, and hardware should not matter.

I just see that *21.04* is not in the list, and that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1350597/1110856) already helped with the fix for *21.04*. Perhaps you should still try it with the latest *22.04* driver? I oversaw in the jungle of tabs that this was only about *21.04*, if someone asks, I can remove the answer.